# go-git clone through proxy

Tags: git, go, google-app-engine-golang

I coding a small application on golang and using go-git to clone git repository, but when I run it through a proxy, it can not to connect to internet.
A piece of code below:

```
url := os.Getenv("APP_DOWNLOAD_LOCATION")
username := "username"
password := "password"
if len(username) > 0 && len(password) > 0 {
    cloneOptions.Auth = &http2.BasicAuth{
        Username: username,
        Password: password,
    }
    cloneOptions.
}
r, err := git.Clone(storer, fs, cloneOptions)
```

I searched but don't have any guide for configure go-git to clone through a proxy.
Has anyone encountered this case yet?
Thanks so much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`auth/basic/username_password/main.go`](https://github.com/go-git/go-git/blob/2637279338ca9736c22b5e15fca916121ae8d089/_examples/clone/auth/basic/username_password/main.go) does not seem to be for proxy authentication though.

For proxy, you would need to set a custom client (as in [`_examples/custom_http/main.go`](https://github.com/src-d/go-git/blob/8b0c2116cea2bbcc8d0075e762b887200a1898e1/_examples/custom_http/main.go#L17-L53), with the [`http.Transport` set with your credentials](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62370543/6309).