# why am i getting dns error from an application but not from my browser

Tags: go, networking, proxy, dns, atom-editor

I am accessing a certain server in my organization's internal network from my browser fine. But when i try  to make the same call from a Go code in Atom. it throws the below error.

```
url := "http://server:port/getcall"

req, _ := http.NewRequest("GET", url, nil)

res, _ := http.DefaultClient.Do(req)
```

```
<body><h1>DNS error</h1>
<p>DNS error (the host name of the page you are looking for does not exist)<br><br>
Please check that the host name has been spelled correctly.<br></p>
```

what could it be ? i tried setting and removing proxies which isnt working.

Comment: Does your browser use a proxy while your go program does not? Are they both running on the same machine? What os are you using?

Comment: yes browser does,and i have the same proxy used in my editor where the program is written. both are running on same machine.os is windows

Comment: Try this here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14661511/setting-up-proxy-for-http-client You should probably set HTTP_PROXY environment variable to the settings the browser uses.

Comment: @Fabian.. thanks this did help resolve the issue. Thank you, have a good day!

Comment: @Fabian: it had worked once and later when i was trying again...i see that its throwing the DNS error again even when the init() has the proxy set . I seem stupid and i cannot figure out why

Comment: Is the proxy address stable? Did something in your network change? Did you change the code? Is HTTP_PROXY also set in the new bash terminal where u call ur code from?

Comment: @Fabian proxy address is dependent on the VPNI  am connected to...however i am using the same one that my browser uses. i have had network changes but i changed proxies accordingly .. code wise i tried adding basic auth creds to the request( Because when the DNS error was resolved, the target server sent me an unauthorized error in the response), then it started giving some weird memory related errors. on reverting which the DNS error came back. I restored a local copy i had of the working code but that isn't working. later i tried setting HTTP_PROXY from bash as well to no avail.

Comment: Is your proxy maybe requiring an auth now? Maybe something changed hm. Did you follow https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51175487/go-http-proxy-with-auth to add basic auth to the request? Otherwise maybe ask ur company admin on this. You could check how ur browser sends proxy requests with wireshark, but that would probably be overkill hm

Answer (score 1):

There is a beautiful [article](https://revs.runtime-revolution.com/golang-dns-resolving-a56ed59981fe) on medium on resolving go's DNS issues. Shortly it referes to the [Name_Resolution](https://golang.org/pkg/net/#hdr-Name_Resolution)  of the `net` package documentation.

In addition to that try to debug domain `resolving` from the command line with a `dig`, `ping` or any other network-related tools. Maybe you r corporate browser has some additional ways to perform DNS resolution in addition to standard once.

Comment: `GODEBUG` is environment variable.

Comment: what should it be set to? the same value as GOPATH ?